# Letter spacing and alignment inside TextView

Tags: android

Let's say I have these 4 numbers:

5 47

33 2

All I want is to align the numbers so the 2 is directly below 47, and 33 directly below 5.

I know I can do this with multiple TextView's, but is possible with 1 or 2? (ie. 1 for each line)

Comment: Android does support \n. So try this "5 47\n33 22".

Answer (score 0):

You can use 2 TextViews and place them in a horizontal LinearLayout, one containing "5\n33" and the other containing "47\n2".